# YouTube videos are not working in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: youtube, video-streaming

I recently installed Ubuntu 18.04 and it is working fine until I opened YouTube. I used both Chrome and Firefox but my YouTube is not working at all.

Could anyone help me with their suggestions?

Comment: Try in terminal `sudo apt-get install flashplugin-installer`

Comment: Can you post the screenshots or explain what exactly is wrong ? If there is some error message share that as well. PS : YouTube working well for me on 18.04 without doing anything. Can you try DailyMotion or some other streaming website ?

Comment: Hi LeonidMew 
While using the above code. I'm getting this. 
E: package 'flashplugin installer' has no installation candidate.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your suggestion. My issue has been resolved.

Comment: @Swastik Bhardwaj Can you share what resolved the problem?

Answer (score 2):

Your flashplayer might be the problem although chrome comes pre-installed with flash player.

Try reinstalling flash plugin by ,

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall flashplugin-installer.
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. My issue has been resolved.

Answer (score 0):

In my case **allow cors chrome extension** was creating the problem. I turn off it and my youtube is working fine.